# GTK3 education ideas

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3

This is a general question about GTK3 (Linux GUI development). I am fairly new to GTK3 and I have been working through the basic tutorials and material found on the [Gnome Developer](http://developer.gnome.org/) website and others such as [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/) and [thecplusplusguy](https://www.youtube.com/user/thecplusplusguy/featured) on YouTube. I have a very basic understanding of GTK3 (and GUI development in general) but I'd like to take my learning to the next level.

I have been searching around the Internet for more GTK3 learning material but all I can find is entry level material.

My thought was to study open source (linux) applications that use GTK3 for their GUI programming. I have tried to find simple open source projects to examine but when I look at the source code (usually on GitHub / GitLab etc) the project are so complex and it is too big a leap for me with my learning. I have also tried to recreate some source code from these open source projects but they have so many dependencies (automake, configure.ac, libraries, links, versions etc).

So if anyone could suggest a resource to further my GTK3 learning I would be very grateful. Or is there a simple / trivial open source project that uses GTK3 that can be studied with relative ease.

Thank for your time.

Lincoln.

Comment: Checkout the gtk-demo application. And find a task that motivates you.

Comment: Thanks for that drahnr. I'll check out gtk-demo application.

Comment: If you like videos you can check this out though it isn't very in-depth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-_EBEr0fxI

Comment: Thanks for that TingPing. I'll watch that video. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: I too struggled with the advanced aspects of GTK3. Now that I have figured them out, I would enjoy sharing (Linux and open source only). Contact me: silrep at emypeople dot net. My project is https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtk-posting/ It is an accounting program for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand you , I am also a beginner with GTK3 + and effectively the documentation released by GNOME it is not greatest. However I suggest you take a look at this section in GNOME developer's site where you can found a list of any documentations of the libraries di GNOME:

https://developer.gnome.org/references

I also suggest you to see at the documentation of GLib and GObject.

Comment: Thanks for that Giorgio. I'll look into GLib and GObject more.